# Cannot pass a search variable in Android search widget

Tags: java, android, xml, search, searchview

I cannot pass my search query which is sent from my `MainActivity.java` to my `SearchResultsActivity.java`, with a search widget as described [on the official guide.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget)

However, I don't want my search widget to be set on the actionbar.

I got no error. My only wish is to get my query displayed thanks to "Log.v".
But the official guide seems only to explain how to call the another activity when we got a search widget inside the actionbar, which isn't our case here.

How to retrieve the variable query in my `MainActivity.java` ?

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.fidbacks_search;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

}
```

**SearchResultsActivity.java**

```
package com.example.fidbacks_search;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
         Log.v("QUERY", "this isn t even being displayed when the search button is pressed");

        // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
          Log.v("QUERY", query.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_results, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="test"
    android:hint="test2" >
</searchable>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fidbacks_search"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.fidbacks_search.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.fidbacks_search.SearchResultsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_results"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
          </intent-filter>
          <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchfield"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false" >

    </SearchView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: cantpassvariable]

Comment: cannot you just call setOnQueryTextListener on your SearchView ?

Comment: What about I want to set complex manipulations with that query :( ? For the time being, I only want to display it on another activity.

Comment: you can do what you wan in your listener, does listener work?

Comment: Thanks you, pskink, you saved me. Listeners do work!
But it seems that they are a bad practice. Should I really use them?
And what is wrong in my code?

Comment: why a bad practice? any link?

Comment: because nearly no documentation is available for those listeners.
=> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget
The official guide reserves 3 lines to say that it is possible, without going further in the explanation as to say "don't do it", but maybe this is only my point of view

Comment: ok try to see which thread the listener is valled from, if its no UI thread you are save, Log.d(Thread.currentThread())

Comment: I don't know how to do that...
But placed on the "onquerysubmit", `Log.d("thread", Thread.currentThread().toString());` gives "Thread[main,5,main]"

Comment: thats bad main means UI thread, so you cannot perform any long blocking operations like network searches, you have to do it in a separate thread

Comment: damn! Does using another activity means using a separate thread... or I got to handle multi threading directly on my mainactivity?

Comment: in your mainactivity, use Executors for example

Comment: thanks, I will test it when I'll work again on it, I don't have access to the project for the time being =) I'll tell you right away!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how you want it done, but I've used SearchView recently and to get what you want, I would simply do the following.

In your activity, add to `onCreate` something like:

```
searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchfield);

SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
searchView.setQueryHint("Enter query here");
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```

Then have your current activity implement `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`'s two methods; the one you are looking for is `onQueryTextSubmit`. Here, use the query that's passed to it and call your `SearchResultsActivity`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchResultsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("query",query);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then have your SearchResultsActivity get the query in `onCreate':

```
query = getIntent().getStringExtra("query");
```

Then, use the query and do whatever you want with it.